# Download PDFs stored in S3 Bucket using Cloudfront URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to download the pdf files which are hosted in S3 Bucket using Cloudfront.I have tried following approaches

1. Using Download attribute in HTML.
2. Adding `Content-Dispostion: Attachment` in `Metadata`.

The *Second Approach* is working if I try to access PDF files directly using S3 URL. But, not working with Cloudfront URL.

Comment: Once you change something stored "behind" CloudFront (e.g. in S3), you need to tell CloudFront to discard any copies it has already cached, or it may continue serving them for some period of time.  Did you create an [invalidation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) request after changing the S3 object metadata?

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot . You are right Its because of Cache. Sorry, for the silly Question. Just started with Cloudfront. Anyways, Thanks for the help.